# How to compose a sentence for possession? Apostrophe or preposition?

Tags: possessives

I would like to know the difference between these sentences:

> I have never seen any of his father's cars (I think it's correct). 
>  I have never seen any cars of his father (I think it's wrong).

In my opinion this is definitely incorrect.

> I have never seen his father's any cars.

What is the commonest way to write the sentence? What's better? An apostrophe to show the possession or a preposition?

Answer (score 1):

> I have never seen any of his father's cars

This is correct. This is the one that any native speaker would use.

> I have never seen any cars of his father

This is wrong, however "I have never seen any *of the* cars of his father" is, as far as I am aware, grammatically correct. But please never write this, it sounds incredibly awkward and no native speaker would speak or write this way unless they were intentionally trying to sound like a Norse god or something.

> I have never seen his father's any cars.

This is completely wrong, I couldn't even understand it without seeing the other two sentences.

In general, we use an apostrophe for possession. There are, however, times when a preposition is used (particularly when trying to sound important). Things like titles (*The Lord of the Rings* rather than *The Rings' Lord*) or announcements (*Will the owner of the blue car outside please move their vehicle*) are places that you might use a preposition.

Comment: Thanks. As far as I know, we can't say *"I have never seen any of John's cars"*, am I right? Do you think *"I have never seen any of the cars of John"* is a correct sentence?

Comment: No, *"I have never seen any of John's cars"* is perfectly fine. *"I have never seen any of the cars of John"* sounds, like I said above, artificially 'old-timey'.

Comment: Thank you. I actually knew it but I just got confused. I have one more question. **"My son took my money without any consent of mine"** sounds correct to me. What do you think about this sentence? I searched on Google and it seems like it is not wrong to say **"of mine."** here.